# Moving nodes around using PyAgrum for a bayesian network

Tags: bayesian-networks, pyagrum

I am working on a project where I am parsing information from a file. I am using the PyAgrum library in a Jupyter notebook. I am able to successfully get the bayesian network I need generated but I am not quite able to figure out the styling. The image I attached below is very long and not very vertical and not the best looking. Is there a way I can determine where the nodes are able to be visualized and is there a way I can get the edges to not cross over each other? I am using the showInference(bayesian_network) function to visualize everything and I want my nodes to keep the same format but to just be moved around in the visualization. I wasn't able to find much in the official documentation so any help would be appreciated. I am also open to any other suggestions of tools that may work better for this sort of visualization. Thank you in advance.[Image of bayesian network where edges cross and nodes are all lined up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RokgB.png)

I have tried looking into the documentation and exploring online but I couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyAgrum uses graphviz for the graph layout. "Dot" usually gives an interesting layout for Bayesian networks. But others (https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/) are also accessible:

```py
import pyAgrum as gum
import pyAgrum.lib.notebook as gnb

bn=gum.fastBN("A1->B1;A1->B2;A1->B3;A2->B1;A2->B3;A3->B3;A3->B4;A4->B4;A5->B2;A5->B3")

gum.config["notebook","graph_layout"]="dot"
gnb.showInference(bn)

gum.config["notebook","graph_layout"]="neato"
gnb.showInference(bn)

gum.config["notebook","graph_layout"]="circo"
gnb.showInference(bn)

gum.config["notebook","graph_layout"]="fdp"
gnb.showInference(bn)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! I must have missed this in the documentation, but this is very useful.

Comment: You haven't missed a thing: this isn't documented at the moment :-( You can even set the position of each node... Hopefully, this will be documented in a future version... :-)

Comment: Hi @Pierre-Henri Wuillemin, I was wondering if you would be able to shed some light on another question I had. I am working on converting my Jupter notebook visualization to a .py file. I am using the pyAgrum.lib.image.exportInference() to get the bayesian network saved but I was wondering if there was anything I could do for the pyAgrum.lib.notebook.showCPTs() and if there was a way I could save the visualization to a .pdf like I am doing for the actual bayesian network. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello @BennettJackson, if you open a new question about this, I will be able to answer :-) In short : showCPT(), as several other notebook function (such as showInformation()), generates HTML string, displayed by jupyter. So you need a way to convert HTML into pdf.

Comment: Hi @Pierre-Henri Wuillemin, Sorry for the delayed follow-up but I went ahead and asked a sort of modified question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78228341/pyagrum-cpts-outside-of-a-jupyter-notebook-environment
Thank you again for your help!