# PyAgrum CPT's outside of a Jupyter Notebook environment

Tags: pyagrum

I am working on converting my Jupter notebook PyAgrum bayesian network visualization to a .py file. I am using the pyAgrum.lib.image.exportInference() to get the bayesian network saved but I was wondering if there was anything I could do for the pyAgrum.lib.notebook.showCPTs() and if there was a way I could save the visualization to a .pdf like I am doing for the actual bayesian network. Or Is there a way I can access the html that the  pyAgrum.lib.notebook.showCPTs() creates and displays in the Jupyter notebook but in my .py file. Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use playwright to generate pdf (or png) from HTML :

```py
import pyAgrum as gum
import pyAgrum.lib.notebook as gnb 


async def exportPotentialAsPDF(p:gum.Potential,filename:str):# in Jupyter
    from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
    
    async with async_playwright() as pw:
        browser = await pw.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.set_content(gnb.getPotential(p))
        await page.pdf(path=filename,
                       print_background=True)
        await browser.close()

async def exportPotentialAsPNG(p:gum.Potential,filename:str):# in Jupyter
    from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
    
    async with async_playwright() as pw:
        browser = await pw.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.set_content(gnb.getPotential(p))
        await page.screenshot(path=filename)
        await browser.close()

bn=gum.fastBN("A->B<-C")
await exportPotentialAsPDF(bn.cpt("B"),"test.pdf")
await exportPotentialAsPNG(bn.cpt("B"),"test.png")
```